# Implementing Set using List

Tags: java, collections

How can i implement a my own List which does not allow duplicate elements some thing like Set using `ArrayList` or `LinkedList`?

Lets assume

```java
 public class  MyList<E> extends AbstractList<E>{

//add
//addAll
//remove
//get
//size

}
```

Comment: How indeed ? What have you tried ?

Comment: Your class shouldn't *extend* `AbstractList<E>`. It should potentially extend `AbstractSet<E>`, and *compose* a list (i.e. there should be a list field).

Comment: It may help to explain why an existing `Set` implementation is not acceptable.

Comment: I am trying to implement a Set using List.I thought before adding check whether element exist and add

Comment: It is not my homework I  am trying to get get the algo I dont need code .I can do myself

Comment: Then why not get the coding started? Of course, you should check that your implementation obeys the `List` contract! In fact, the `List` contract _is_ your algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@override
public boolean add(..<E>)
{
//implement code to reject duplicates
// returns **false** if object already present in the list
}
```

Comment: +1 and obviously return false if the item didnt get inserted as it is already in the list. also need to override the `addAll` method

Comment: @cowls the list contract _requires_ that `.add()` returns true

Comment: @fge Actually it says as specified by `Collections.add()` which states: `Returns: true if this collection changed as a result of the call `

Comment: @cowls yes, but the Javadoc for `List` says that it should return `true`. Mixing the `Set` and `List` contract does not look like a good idea...

Comment: @fge Possibly open to interpretation, it says: `true (as specified by Collection.add(E)) ` personally I like the idea

Answer (score 1):

You should try to use `LinkedHashSet` instead of `MyList`

Comment: `Set` does not implement all methods in `List` however (for instance, you cannot `.get(int)` on a `Set`)

Comment: @fge At least they are all `Collection` , and you can iterator on `Set` to . but yes you can not do things like random access

Comment: LinkedHashset is more about insertion order not duplication

Answer (score 1):

Well strictly speaking you can't do that without breaking the `List` contract.

Suppose you have:

```
public class  MyList<E> extends AbstractList<E>{
    ...
}
```

The fact that you are extending `AbstractList` means that you are indirectly implementing `List`.  And this means that certain operations have to behave in specific ways.  For instance `List.equals()` is specified as *"Returns true if and only if the specified object is also a list, both lists have the same size, **and all corresponding pairs of elements in the two lists are equal**."*  But that is totally the wrong semantic for a set, and certainly for a `Set`.  In a true set, the order of elements is irrelevant to equality.

Now you could ignore this (programs do worse) ... but there is a chance that it could bite you.

Anyway, a more semantically correct implementation of a set using a list would look more like this:

```
public class MySet<E> implements Set<E> {
    private List<E> list = ...
    // implement the Set API by delegating to the list object ...
}
```

---

Incidentally, the spec of the `List.add(E)` operation's return value only a problem if you apply a pedantic and nonsensical reading to the javadocs.  The `List` javadoc explicitly allows list implementations that refuse to add specific elements.  My take is that the phrase *"true (as specified by Collection.add(E))"* is applies to the case where the add operation actually changes the list.  If it doesn't change the list, the `Collection.add(E)` method spec *actually* says that the result *should* be `false` ... and so does common sense.